# Custom product needs real implementation of itertools.product

Tags: python, generator, product, python-itertools

I am trying to implement custom itertools.product because I don't to create the whole cartesian product but I want last couple of elements to be fixed. I just copied the code from here https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
    def product(*args, repeat=1):
        # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
        # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
        pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
        result = [[]]
        for pool in pools:
            result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
        for prod in result:
            yield tuple(prod)
```

and tried to customize. However, even without any change it has different behaviour than

```
for el in itertools.product(range(2), 30)
    print(el)
```

Cases 1: the code snippet (function product) I provide from docs. First (as you can see the code) create the whole result and then yield one by one. But

Case 2.

```
for el in itertools.product(range(2), 30)
    print(el)
```

Yields the elements immediately which is something I would expect from generator because sometimes the product doesn't fit into my memory.

Does anybody know the real implementation of itertools.product?

Comment: In the CPython source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f5088006ca8e9654fbc3de119462f0ab764e408b/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2192. The function `product_next` is maybe the most interesting, to see how it yields item by item.

Comment: It's not clear why you don't just use `itertools.product`...

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close to the [actual implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/42f54d1f9244784fec99e0610aa05a5051e594bb/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2192):

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    npools = len(pools)
    try:
        result = [pool[0] for pool in pools]
    except IndexError:
        return
    yield result
    indices = [0] * npools
    p = npools - 1
    while p >= 0:
        pool = pools[p]
        indices[p] += 1
        try:
            result[p] = pool[indices[p]]
        except IndexError:
            indices[p] = 0
            result[p] = pool[indices[p]]
            p -= 1
            continue
        else:
            p = npools - 1
            yield tuple(result)
```

This is how it looks when applied to your original problem:

```
>>> big = product(range(2), repeat=30)
>>> next(big)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> next(big)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
>>> next(big)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
>>> next(big)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```